# CSS3 Animation browser compatibility issues

Tags: html, css, animation

In my html page, i have this code for some style (blinking text)

```
#blink{
 -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration:.3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: colours;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: none;
-moz-animation-direction: normal;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-name: colours;
-moz-animation-timing-function: none;
}
     @-webkit-keyframes colours {
 0% {color: white; color: #00FF00;color: white;}
 25% {color: #00FF00;}
 50% {color: white;}
 75% {color: #00FF00;}
100% {color: white;}


@-moz-keyframes colours {
     0% {color: white; color: #00FF00; color: white;}
     25% {color: #00FF00;}
     50% {color: white;}
     75% {color: #00FF00;}
    100% {color: white;}
 }
```

The problem is, this works in google chrome and other browsers using span id but it doesn't seem to be blinking in Firefox, why is this, is there anything I need to add?

Comment: Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink - why the html `blink` tag was removed

Comment: You forgot the closing `}` for `@-webkit-keyframes`, so the `@-moz-keyframes` couldn't get recognized. Also FF supports css animations [without prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation)

Answer (score 0):

use like this css

```css
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: yellow;}
    50%  {background-color: blue;}
    100% {background-color: green;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: yellow;}
    50%  {background-color: blue;}
    100% {background-color: green;}
}
</style>
```